# How to handle empty JSONObject in Processing?

Tags: processing, json

Hi I am using loadJSONObject function in Processing IDE to receive a JSON Object from a URL.
Following is my code:

```
      JSONObject jsonUserLocations = loadJSONObject("http://smrt.utd.sg/eLocation/getLocs.php?userId="+usrID+"&sTime="+strtTime+"&eTime="+endTym);
```

This code works when the php returns some data (for some users). 
The problem occurs when it doesn't return any data. (php doesn't return any data when there is no data, browser shows a blank page. this means user has no location data)

At this instance, the Processing IDE gives me an error saying;

> a jsonobject text must begin with {

My question is how can I handle empty JSON Object in this type of situation? I need to skip if this is empty and request data for next user. Your help is much appreciated.
Thanks,
Hasala

### Edit:

This is sample json object I receive when there is data.

> {"locations":[{"latitude":"1.3809274","longitude":"103.7654596","startTime":"1421918587868","duration":"0","accuracy":"30"},{"latitude":"1.3805307","longitude":"103.7661015","startTime":"1421941711737","duration":"0","accuracy":"45"},{"latitude":"1.3805304","longitude":"103.7660959","startTime":"1421942011727","duration":"0","accuracy":"45"},{"latitude":"1.3799822","longitude":"103.7658037","startTime":"1421942311835","duration":"0","accuracy":"82.5"}],"success":1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

You could read the String form the URL first, and if it's blank, don't bother with the parsing.

Or you could just catch the exception that Processing throws:

```
try{
   JSONObject jsonUserLocations = loadJSONObject("http://smrt.utd.sg/eLocation/getLocs.php?userId="+usrID+"&sTime="+strtTime+"&eTime="+endTym);
}
catch(JSONException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
   //json was blank, do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you said.
It gives me "cannot find a class or type named "JSONException" error.

Comment: @Hasala You have to import it. Or just use Exception.

Comment: Importing it didn't work .I tried using Exception and now it works. Thanks for your help.